# Dash has odd texture since update

Tags: unity-dash

Ever since I updated, my Dash has had an odd texture glitch, showing a kind of green and orange tiled texture. I'd post a picture but can't. The major point is that it is not the standard black texture it used to be.

What's causing this? And secondly, does this indicate anything major?

Comment: Is it related to the current wallpaper color palette? Do a **screenshot** (std. Ubuntu app.), but with 4 second delay. *This should capture the entire screen.* Then clip the top corner (too attach).

Comment: my current reputation is not high enough to post pictures, when it is i'll post a screen cap

Comment: @ChristineElizabethMeyer Post the picture on imgur or imgbay and then paste the link here.